# Centring column header text in dataGridView

Tags: c#

I have small problem, when I center text in column in dataGridView like this

```
dataGridView1.ColmnHeadersDefaultStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
```

Some times I can see strange tendency to pull the text to the left side cell.

[image]

like on this image, I will appreciate if somebody can help me with this small and annoying problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your columns are sortable, there is some place on the right for the sort arrows.

Comment: Oh... it's true, but why some colmns are sortable and some aren't, when I didn't setting nothing like this ?

Comment: It depends how the Datagridview was filled. If bounded to a DataTable, all columns shall be sortable (or none of them). If bounded to a collection of objects, columns are deduced from internal/public properties and column sort mode depends if the property type is IComparable or not.